# Vuex: How to avoid errors when updating store (or: how to correctly watch for changes in store)?

Tags: javascript, vuex, store, vuejs3

I am building an app that contains several entries of different months. To show them, the user chooses a month (with a slider) and the app returns the machting entries. Only months (or better: month-year combinations) exist if there are corresponding entries. Until here, this works fine.

However, when I want to add an entry, I get weird errors: `Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node`.

I noticed that it all works fine if the corresponding month of the new entry already exists.

To get the current month-year combinations, I use a getter:

```
entriesMonths(state) {
  // Return an ordered arrays of all months present among entries
  var entriesMonths = [];
  var months_unique = [];
  var current_index = 0;

  const entries = state.entries;

  //Sort entries
  var order = -1;
  entries.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = new Date(a.date);
    b = new Date(b.date);
    var results = a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    return results * order;
  });

  // Add entry if not present yet
  for (var i in entries) {
    var month = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MM");
    var year = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("YYYY");
    var displayMonth = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MMMM YYYY");

    if (!months_unique.includes(displayMonth)) {
      // Push if displayMonth not existent yet
      months_unique.push(displayMonth);
      entriesMonths.push({
        index: current_index,
        month: month,
        year: year,
        displayMonth: displayMonth,
      });
      current_index++;
    }
  }

  return entriesMonths;
```

To also get the months after an entry was added, I use the getter within a computed property:

```
computed: {
  entriesMonths() {
    return this.$store.getters.entriesMonths;
  },
},
```

If I use the getter in `data()`, I don't get an error after adding a new entry, but the app also does not show the new entry.

Adding the new entry to the store seems to work fine. So does the re-calculation of `entriesMonths` (I used `debugger` to check).

The full code can be found on Github: https://github.com/juliangermek/haushaltsbuch

The error message doesn't really tell what is wrong (and I don't think that it is an internal bug) and I can't find out what really is. Can you make sense of this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error says that something external to Vue has modified the DOM. Are you using jQuery or other 3rd party library that can possibly manipulate the DOM outside of Vue?

Comment: I think not. I'm using https://momentjs.com/, but that doesn't manipulate the DOM. I also can't make out where exactly the error is occuring..

Comment: Try to isolate the issue - i.e. use local component data instead of Vuex, or try Incognito mode of the browser to eliminate the possibility of buggy extension.

Comment: When I just list all the elements of `entriesMonths` with `<p>` and `v-for`, adding new entries works fine (both with and without vuex). As soon as I want to display `ion-slide` with `<p>` and `v-for`, it raises the errors. Going incognito or changing browser doesn't change that. Therefore, it seems like `ion-slides` does not like being updated, right? Any ideas what could be done about this?